# Biblioteca que realize pesquisas no Google

Tags: android

Gente tenho uma duvida aqui sou iniciante no Android, eu quero produzir um APP que faça pesquisas em sites como exemplo CasasBahia,Casa&Video e etc e mostre em ordem de preços os produtos, alguem conhece alguma biblioteca que faça esse tipo de pesquisa?

Comment: Matheus, você tentou fazer alguma coisa? Teve algum progresso?

Comment: Eu não conheço nada do Android Studio, eu só fiz aplicativos pelo AppInventor e estou querendo partir pro Android, dai eu não sei por onde começar, eu queria saber pelo menos o nome de bibliotecas que me ajudassem a fazê-la que o Layout eu me viro.Já tentei dar uma procurada no Google sobre isso mas nao obtive algum resultado pelo menos meio parecido com o que procuro

Answer (score 1):

Nativa do Android não tem, mas você pode fazer comunicação com a [API REST do Buscapé](http://developer.buscape.com.br/portal/buscape/api-de-produtos/introducao), por exemplo.

Comment: Obrigado, irei dar uma olhada nisso, nem sabia que a Buscapé tinha site de desenvolvimento kkkkkk

Comment: Só pra avisar, o salto de dificuldade de aprendizado do AppInventor para o Java do Android Studio é gigantesco. Vai ter que estudar muito para desenvolver o que você precisa.